# Calculator final project in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, homework, calculator

In my final project for my Python course, I am required to create a calculator program. I really need someone to look over my code and tell me if I have met all the requirements for this project.

Here are the requirements:

> For the final project, you are to write a calculator program in Python
>   with the following characteristics:
>
> - It must be at least 50 lines of code excluding comments
> - It must have the following functions:+,-,*,/, SQRT, and work with decimal numbers.
> - It must be all text, no high resolution graphics
> - It must automatically copy the result to the operating system clipboard
> - It must work as a functional calculator (calculations can be entered over and over)
>
> Please submit the source code only (.py), no object code (I will
>   compile on receipt)
>
> NOTE:
>
> 1. This assignment is graded on a pass/fail basis; there is no partial credit or resubmissions. Be sure you understand ALL of the
>      requirements.
> 2. Solutions that require the user install any software will NOT be accepted (in case you are not sure, this means NO Pyperclip.)
>
> WARNING: All submissions will be checked for plagiarism using
>   SafeAssign or other plagiarism checker.

I completed the project, but because this is a pass/fail project I want to be 200% sure I have met every requirement. I am also open to any other feedback that would sharpen my Python skills.

Menu

```
def main():
    #Menu
    print("=======================")
    print("Welcome to Calculator")
    print("By: Tyler Harris")
    print("=======================")
    print("Menu: ")
    print("[1] Calculator")
    print("[2] Instructions")
    print("[3] Exit")
    print("=======================")
    choice = input("Please select an option: ")
    if choice == '1':
        calculator()
    elif choice == '2':
        instructions()
        main()
    elif choice == '3':
        print("Thank you for using Calculator.")
    else:
        print("Not an option, try again:")
        main()
```

Calculator

```
def calculator():
    result=0        #Resets calulator.
    try:
        while True:
            print("Last Result: "+str(result))

            #Number 1 input.
            if result == 0:
                num1= int(input("First Number: "))
            if result != 0:     
                num1=result

            #Operator input.
            #Checks for input of special operators 'c', 'sqrt', and 'esc'.
            operator=input("Opertaor: ").lower()
            if operator == "c":
                print("Calculator cleared")
                calculator()
            if operator=="sqrt":
                result=(sqrt(num1))
                print("Result: "+str(result))
                continue
            if operator=="esc":
                main()
            if operator.isdigit():      #Throw error if operator is a number.
                raise Exception()

            #Number 2 input.    
            num2= int(input("Second Number: "))
            #Operator calls.
            if operator=="+":
                result=(add(num1,num2))
            elif operator=="-":
                result=(sub(num1,num2))
            elif operator=="*":
                result=(mult(num1,num2))
            elif operator=="/":
                result=(div(num1,num2))


            #Copy result to System's clipboard and display the result.    
            copy2clip(str(result))      
            print("=======================")
            print("Result: "+str(result))
            print("copied to clipboard")
            print("=======================")

    #Catch any errors and reset calculator            
    except Exception:
        print("=======================")
        print("Error Please try again.")
        calculator()
    else:
        calculator()
```

Operators

```
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2
def sub(num1,num2):
    return num1 - num2
def mult(num1,num2):
    return num1 * num2
def div(num1,num2):
    return num1 / num2
def sqrt(num1):
    return (num1**(1/2.0))
```

Instructions

```
def instructions():
    print("=======================")
    print(format('Calculator','^25s'))
    print("=======================")
    print("Available operators")
    print("+: Addition")
    print("-: Subtraction")
    print("*: Multiplication")
    print("/: Division")
    print("sqrt: Square Root")
    print("c: Clear Calculator")
    print("esc: Exit Calculator")
    print("=======================")

def copy2clip(txt):
    cmd='echo '+txt.strip()+'|clip'
    return subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I would suggest you don't use `raise Exception`, instead provide a bit more info i.e. `raise ValueError('Operator must be a digit')`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time for a full review, but one thing I did pick up on and wants checking is the requirement to "work with decimal numbers." It may be worth clarifying whether it's fine to use floating point numbers, or whether you're specifically expected to use the decimal library: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 10):

You are using function calls as if they were goto labels.  That is a huge sin: it makes your program spaghetti code.  If you want a loop, then write a loop.  For example, `main()` should look like:

```
def main():
    while True:
        #Menu
        print("=======================")
        print("Welcome to Calculator")
        print("By: Tyler Harris")
        print("=======================")
        print("Menu: ")
        print("[1] Calculator")
        print("[2] Instructions")
        print("[3] Exit")
        print("=======================")
        choice = input("Please select an option: ")
        if choice == '1':
            calculator()
        elif choice == '2':
            instructions()
        elif choice == '3':
            print("Thank you for using Calculator.")
            break
        else:
            print("Not an option, try again:")
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    elif choice == '2':
        instructions()
        main()
```

Ummm, that's probably not exactly what you want.
Python lacks a `goto` statement, so the usual idiom would be to wrap the whole thing in some sort of `while` loop, perhaps `while True`.
Consider an input sequence of "2 2 2 2 2", or "z z z z z".
You'll wind up pushing `main` onto the call stack again, and again, and again....

Your locals never go out of scope,
so their [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html#weak-references) [count](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#finalization-and-de-allocation) never decrements and they won't be deallocated and tidied up.

tl;dr: leaking stack frames is Bad, don't do it.

```
            print("Last Result: "+str(result))
```

Usual idiom would be `print('Last Result:', result)`, but no harm done.

```
                num1 = int(input("First Number: "))
```

The requirements seemed pretty clear about "...must work with **decimal** numbers."
You chose to invoke `int()` rather than `float()`.

```
            if result != 0:     
                num1 = result
```

I can't imagine how that corresponds to The Right Thing.
If you want a sentinel, `None` would be much better than `0`,
just consider a sequence like `2 + 1 = - 3 =` (which yields zero).
Perhaps there's a reason for assigning the accumulator to `num1`, but I'm not seeing it.
It appears you have discarded the user input.

```
            operator = input("Opertaor: ").lower()
```

Typo.

```
                calculator()
```

Same criticism as above. Python lacks `goto`, and you're leaking stack frames here.

```
            if operator == "sqrt":
                result = (sqrt(num1))
                print("Result: "+str(result))
                continue
```

It is apparent that I'm not understanding why you are using the `result` accumulator versus the `num1` user input.
On most calculators, repeated clicking of the √ key would yield repeated assignment of `result = sqrt(result)`.
I'm a little concerned about `num1` versus `result` confusion.

```
            if operator=="esc":
                main()
```

Same remark about leaking stack frames.
A `return` statement would be usual, here.

```
            if operator.isdigit():
```

This seems a bit restrictive.
Better to unconditionally raise an "unrecognized operator" error.

```
            num2 = int(input("Second Number: "))
```

Same criticism as above, the "decimal" instructions are pretty clear about calling `float()`.

```
                result = (add(num1,num2))
```

All four of these assignments seem pretty weird,
as for a typical calculator we'd be accumulating `result = add(result, num2)`.
This is a consequence of the `num1` assignment above.
Also, please discard the `(`extraneous parentheses`)`.

```
def sqrt(num1):
    return (num1**(1/2.0))
```

This works fine, but do consider the usual idiom of simply calling `math.sqrt()`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the first point of why it is bad to keep calling main() - basically each time you call a method, you are 'entering' that method. But you never exit the method - you just keep going deeper into the wormhole with each main() call. As JH is saying, each time you call a method you are putting more data onto the stack, but since the methods never are allowed to exit, the data is never freed, which eventually means you run out of space and the application will stop working.

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes. Is there anything else I have missed that could be considered bad practice?

Main

```
def main():
#Operators are +,-,*,/
#Special operator are c and esc
calculator()
```

Calculator

```
def calculator():
num1 = 0        #Resets calulator.
clear = True       #Checks if calculator is cleared
while True:
    try:
        print("Last result: ",num1)

        #Number 1 input.
        if clear == True:
            num1= float(input("First Number: "))    

        #Operator input.
        #Checks for input of special operators 'c', 'sqrt', and 'esc'.
        operator=input("Operator: ").lower()
        if bool(re.search('^(?=.*[0-9]$)', operator)) == True: #Check if operator contains a number
            raise ValueError(" Operator must be +,-,*,/,sqrt, or c") #Throw error if operator is a number.
        elif operator == "c":
            num1 = 0
            clear = True
            print("Calculator cleared")
        elif operator=="sqrt":
            num1=(sqrt(num1))
            print("result: ",num1)
            continue
        elif operator=="esc":
            sys.exit(0)

        #Number 2 input.    
        if operator == "c":
            pass
        else:
            num2= float(input("Second Number: "))

        #Operator calls.
        if operator=="+":
            num1= add(num1,num2)
            clear = False
        elif operator=="-":
            num1= sub(num1,num2)
            clear = False
        elif operator=="*":
            num1= mult(num1,num2)
            clear = False
        elif operator=="/":
            num1= div(num1,num2)
            clear = False

        #Copy num1 to System's clipboard and display the num1.    
        copy2clip(str(num1))      
        print("=======================")
        print("result: ",num1)
        print("copied to clipboard")
        print("=======================")

    #Catch any errors and reset calculator            
    except ValueError as error:
        print("=======================")
        print("Error: ",repr(error))
        pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)... You can post a [new question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and mention the question/post above, to link the posts.